# How to configure Wildfly 9 to failover HTTP sessions

Tags: java, session, wildfly, failover

I'm really struggling to configure Wildfly 9 to cluster/failover its sessions...

I keep reading that wildfly in standalone-ha mode will automatically discover peers and automatically share sessions, but it's clearly not working for me.

I have setup 3 AWS EC2 servers which all have the same configuration.  They all run the same versions of everything and have the same webapp .war file deployed to each of them.  This webapp works fine, I can log in to the app which maintains a simple session variable to verify that I am logged in.  I've launched each server with standalone-ha.xml configuration files but logging into one doesn't allow be to access the session in any of the others.

I've tried all the things I can think of, but don't know how to diagnose the issue as I don't know how the servers identify each other.

I've manually deployed the war file on each server but placing the file into .../standalone/deployments/

Each has a fully open firewall...

Oh - I set the muticast address on the command line to 230.0.0.4 (That number came from a guide, and I have literally no understanding of it) and each is bound (-b) to the internal IP of the server...

Any help appreciated...

Comment: In AWS EC2 multicast traffic is not allowed and thus MPING will not work. See https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JGroupsS3PING

Comment: @FedericoSierra You're a star - didn't really consider that the AWS element could be breaking it...  If you wanted to put that as an answer I could mark it as Correct :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you must consider that in AWS EC2 multicast traffic is not allowed and thus `MPING` will not work.

See http://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JGroupsS3PING

An example how to implement `S3Ping` http://aws.typepad.com/awsaktuell/2013/10/elastic-jboss-as-7-clustering-in-aws-using-ec2-s3-elb-and-chef.html